# Cannot give more than 50 points when starting bounty?

Tags: discussion, support

I looked up the rules for setting a bounty on my question from the page - https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

> To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question and allocate anywhere between 50 and 500 reputation, in 50-point increments.

I am not sure if I can offer only 50 the first time because I have only 100 points now. I wanted to confirm if my first bounty can only be 50 and can be incremented later by 50 points at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next level of bounty past 50 would be 100.  If you put a 100 reputation bounty on the question, you would be at the 0 reputation level.  However, since Stack Overflow does not let anyone get below the 1 reputation level, you would be losing more reputation than you have available.  Once you get to 101 reputation or above, the 100 reputation bounty should be open to you.

Also, you can't increase bounties.  Once you set one, you need to award it or wait for it to expire before adding one for higher reputation.